# Password authentication failed for user when using new docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using django-cookiecutter template and for the second time for new project. And it fails to connect to postgres with following error:

```
postgres_1  | 2018-04-30 14:54:09.747 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  | 2018-04-30 14:54:10.029 UTC [28] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "IViLGLIEWLBDGBnsAuoOEhtFaKrqKxfX"
postgres_1  | 2018-04-30 14:54:10.029 UTC [28] DETAIL:  Role "IViLGLIEWLBDGBnsAuoOEhtFaKrqKxfX" does not exist.
postgres_1  |   Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
django_1    | PostgreSQL is unavailable (sleeping)...
```

One of the maintainers explained this:

```
the thing is, every time you bootstrap the project POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD get reset to a newly-generated random values
```

I tried to remove all docker containers but no success any idea how am i able to solve this? I dont have the old credentials to replace them.

Comment: I'm running into this exact problem every time I deploy my project with Docker. I'm not sure how your answer solves this long term. Does it still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of https://github.com/webyneter (contributor to django-cookiecutter)

The solution is following:

- To see existing volumes: `docker volume ls`
- To remove the respective volumes `docker volume rm <your project_slug>_postgres_backup_local <your project_slug>_postgres_data_local`